# Dynamically updating select list based on another select list

Tags: excel, vba

I want fill a drop down list based on user selection in another. Can't find anything related to it online.

I have a workbook called **lookupDept** containing the following table:

```
A   B
==  ==============================
BS  Business School
CG  Chemical Engineering
```

where *column A* has the defined name **deptCode** and *column B* has the defined name **deptName**. I have a second workbook called **lookupModule** which contains the following table:

```
A       B                                                   C
======  ==================================================  ==
BSA005  Organisational Behaviour                            BS
BSA007  Skills for Study                                    BS
CGA001  Fluid Mechanics I MEng & BEng Status                CG
CGA002  Stagewise Processes                                 CG
```

I'm trying to update **cbo_moduleCode** on my form to select a range where *column A* in **lookupDept** matches *column C* in **lookupModule**. This is the code I'm using:

So if the user picks *BS - Business School* on the form (which is extracted from the **lookupDept** workbook, I want all the fields containing *BS* in column C of the **lookupModule** workbook to selected. This is the code I'm using so far:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim c_deptCode As Range
    Dim c_deptName As Range

    Dim deptCodes As Variant
    Dim deptNames As Variant

    Dim ws_dept As Worksheet
    Dim ws_misc As Worksheet
    Set ws_dept = Worksheets("lookupDept")
    Set ws_misc = Worksheets("lookupMisc")

    ' Assign each range to an array containing the values
    deptCodes = Choose(1, ws_dept.Range("deptCode"))
    deptNames = Choose(1, ws_dept.Range("deptName"))

    ' Create deptcode+deptname cbo
    For i = 1 To ws_dept.Range("deptCode").Rows.Count
        CombinedName = deptCodes(i, 1) & " - " & deptNames(i, 1)
        cbo_deptCode.AddItem CombinedName
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the items on the fly once the first combobox is selected. This code is a sample that might lead you in the right direction:

```
Private Sub cbo_deptCode_Change()
Dim lLoop As Long, rgLoop As range

For lLoop = 1 To Me.cbo_moduleCode.ListCount

    Me.cbo_moduleCode.RemoveItem 0

Next lLoop

Sheets("lookupModule").[a1].CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
Sheets("lookupModule").[a1].CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Left(Me.cbo_deptCode.Value, 2)

For Each rgLoop In Sheets("lookupModule").[a1].CurrentRegion.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(1).Cells
    If Len(rgLoop) > 0 Then
        Me.cbo_moduleCode.AddItem rgLoop & " - " & rgLoop.Offset(, 1)
    End If
Next rgLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any other method where you don't have to use auto filter?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when there is a single row in lookupModule

Comment: what result do you get with just one row? Is there a matching row, or none at all?

Comment: There is one matching row but it isn't picked up. It only seems to work with more than one matching row